# How To Tell When A JSON Request Is Received In Wordpress?

Tags: json, wordpress, json-api

I am using a [JSON API plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) for wordpress to allow me to work with the sites content in a phonegap application I'm building.

However due to the complexity of some of the content on the site (caused by shortcodes outputting graphs, sliders etc..) these aren't suitable to be displayed in the mobile app. I need to remove the shortcodes from the JSON output.

I have found that I can hook into `the_content` filter in wordpress and use `remove_shortcode` to take out the necessary shortcodes. But the problem is I can only do this when I access the json url via my browser.

For example, I may use `http://example.com?json=1` to return recent posts. If I type this in my url bar I can parse the url, determine that `json=1` is there and strip the shortcodes.

However when I am doing an ajax (JSONP) request from my mobile application, it doesn't appear to be able to check the url for the `json` parameter, thus my shortcodes are not being stripped. I can't even pass in any headers either as they won't make it because of the nature of `JSONP` requests I believe.

Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can figure out when a JSON request from my mobile application is received, so that I can then remove the shortcodes?

Something like

```
if(is_json()){
//remove shortcodes
}
```

And before it's brought up, I have asked this on the [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155448/hook-into-the-content-filter-for-json-api-only) but to no avail

Update: 
Here is the code I use for the ajax request from the mobile app

```
  $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.example.com/?json=1",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    async: true,
                    success: function(result) {
                        app.populate(result)
                    },
                    error: function(request, error) {
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompted by one of the comments, I found what I needed in the JSON-API plugin files.

If you look in `json-api/models/post.php` there's a function `set_content_value()` which shows where the plugin is pulling in the content. Here you can modify it as needed, in my case I used it to remove certain shortcodes with the Wordpress `remove_shortcode()` function

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the remove_shortcode function anytime your plugin serves content to a client?

Could you also give us the name / url of your plugin?
Maybe a bit of code woudln't hurt either. Would you mind giving use your phonegap application's API request code snippet?

Thanks.

Comment: But how do I tell when the json api plugin is being used? I've updated my post with the ajax request code. I've linked the plugin used in the first line of the post http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: Within the core.php file of the plugin, there are a few methodes depending on the content type you wish to retrieve. For example there's the `getPost()` function which returns the a JSON object for a given post ID. Just override the return statement with your `remove_shortcode()` function. You'll have to do the same for each function you are using through your API (you should do something like this: `$response["content"] = remove_shortcode($reponse["content"]);` before the return statement).

Comment: Ok so what you said got me thinking a bit more. I had already tried messing around in the plugin looking for where the content was pulled in, but I failed to find it. The `getPost()` in the core.php , while it wasn't the correct place, lead me to the `post.php` file. And in there I found where the content was pulled in, as well as the filters applied. I was simply able to add in my `remove_shortcode()` there and it stripped the shortcodes out! Thanks a bunch